# Divide $x^8+16a^4x^4+256a^8$ by $x^2+2ax+4a^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Divide $x^8+16a^4x^4+256a^8$ by $x^2+2ax+4a^2$.

$\begin{align}x^8+16a^4x^4+256a^8&=(x^4+16a^4)^2-16a^4x^4\\&=(x^4+16a^4)^2-(4a^2x^2)^2\\&=(x^4+16a^4+4a^2x^2)(x^4+16a^4-4a^2x^2)\\&=[(x^2+4a^2)^2-4a^2x^2][(x^2-4a^2)^2+4a^2x^2]\\&=(x^2+4a^2+2ax)(x^2+4a^2-2ax)[(x^2-4a^2)^2+4a^2x^2]\\\\x^2+2ax+4a^2&=\dfrac{x^3-(2a)^3}{x-2a}\end{align}$

This is the most I can simplify the two expressions. Unfortunately, I see no common factor that can be cancelled out to simplify the problem. A straight-up term by term division is quite tedious and does not look like the way to solve this question. Any insight or help is appreciated.

Comment: "*I see no common factor*" $\;-\;$ Look more closely.

Comment: You could just use long division

Comment: It might be helpful to think of the expressions as $x^8 +(ka)^4x^4 +(ka)^8$ and $x^2+(ka)x+(ka)^2$, and therefor can be rewritten as $x^8 + b^4x^4 + b^8$ and $x^2+bx+b^2$, where obviously $k=2$. Ridding yourself of numbers is often helpful.

Comment: See the first factor of the first polynomial (simplified).

Comment: you seem to have trouble when expressions are written in an unfamiliar order. Not entirely sure how to practice with that, unless it is to take pencil and separate slip of paper, then every time something new appears,  write it down as it is and in your favorite order. Here,$x^2 + 4 a^2 + 2ax  =   x^2 + 2ax + 4  a^2.$   This is the first expression in your last line, as the others have said